# Testing expected file io

Tags: automated-testing

There is an application/script that will write files and create directories. Depending on what path it takes (error, success, parameters). How could this be tested in a more automated fashion? I use find and wc -l and bash and eyeballs currently to validate the expected outcome for a suite of tests. Are there tools that are used for this type of testing?

I do not have a framework available for mocking i/o. Even with this though, mocking still is not quite the same.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is on Linux you could run the program via strace and make it log the all open and opendir calls.

```
strace -e open,opendir command
```

The program will run and whenever a file or directory is opened a log will be printed on stdout.

You can use this method to log any syscalls be adding them to the -e section.

You may need to add -f if the program forks or is loaded by a script.

If you want to mock IO there is a tool called FIO that will generate lots of different io patterns.

You could string it together with bats which provides a simple shell script based test framework

Answer (score 0):

If your application assumes interactive input you can use [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) program to supply parameters. Success can be checked by assessing `$?` [special variable](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22006) value, i.e. if it is `0` - previous command was successful, otherwise not.

If you are interested in metrics in terms of time taken or resources used - you can wrap your application in [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(Unix)) command.

With regards to "framework" you can consider [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) which provides [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) which can execute arbitrary commands and programs, evaluate output, measure time taken, run it with multiple users/threads, etc.